# CSS: Standardize space between thumbnails in a row

Tags: css

I've got a 780px width container and I would like to fit 4 thumbnails per row (I have multiple rows).

How do I standardize the space between the thumbnails so that the first & fourth thumbnail in a row stick to the 'wall' of the container?

My code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
    <li class="card package">Image</li>
   ...and so on
</ul>
```

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam I set it using fixed width with fixed margin but there's still some space on the right of the fourth thumbnail.

Comment: Assign a class first and last to your thumbnails and give them a padding-left/margin-left 0. than give the other ones a margin/padding left and/or right.

Comment: i suppose you want to have more than 4 .card elements inside your .thumbnails container, so to say, multiple 'rows'? otherwise, use a margin-right on '.card', then a margin-right of zero on '.card:last-child'

Answer (score 1):

For example if you need to have 20px spaces in between you can do this:

`780-60=720` space available for blocks

`720/4=180` your block width

```
.thumbnails .card{
width:180px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.thumbnails .card:first-child{
margin-left:0px;
}
```

Since you have edited your question, I would suggest having multiple ul for each row.

If you insist on having one:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild this might be helpful:

`.thumbnails .card:first-child, .thumbnails .card:nth-child(n5) {`

Comment: in the second row the first card isnt a first child

Comment: yeah, I thought it was only one row as in the original question :)

Comment: if you use `margin-right` instead `margin-left`, you could achieve the same result and don't need `:first-child` then

Answer (score 1):

use css3 to cut of the margin on every 4th element

```
li.card { 
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
li.card:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnjFw/)

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you. Define your width in container related your thumbnail's width

```
    #container {
    width:200px;
    }
    #container ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ychX4/

You can use this action by nth-child Css selectors. But Internet Explorer browser NOT support. 
Ref : http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Good Luck..)